# KafkaListenerEndpointContainer Could not create Kafka transaction with Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using spring-Kafka 2.2.2.RELEASE(org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1) and spring-boot(2.1.1).  I am not able to execute a transaction because my listener is not able to get a partition assigned. I created the configuration suggested for exactly once consumer. I am trying to configure  a transactional Listener Container and Exactly Once Processing

I configured the producer and consumer using transaction manager, producer with transaction id, consumer with isolation.level=read_committed.

```java
@Bean(name = "producerFactory")
        public ProducerFactory<String, MyObject> producerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG,true);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,"txApp");
            DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, KafkaSerializer> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
            producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("tx.");

                    return producerFactory;
        }



@Bean
    public KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager() {
        KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(producerFactory());
        // ...
        return kafkaTransactionManager;
    }

@Bean(name="appTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<String,MyObject> kafkaTemplate(){
        KafkaTemplate<String, MyObject> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(
                producerFactory());
        return kafkaTemplate;
    }

//Consumer

@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                          ConsumerFactory kafkaConsumerFactory,
                                                                          KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager());
        return factory;
    }

//in the Consumer
   @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "ingest", concurrency = "4")
    public void listener(@Payload MyObject message,
                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

...

// In my producer

myTemplate.executeInTransaction(t-> t.send(kafkaConfig.getTopicName(), myMessage));
```

I am expecting to see the message arriving to my listener, but when I execute the producer I am getting below error:

```
22-07-2019 10:21:55.283 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR  o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete request.id= request.caller=  - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=ingest] User provided listener org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerConsumerRebalanceListener failed on partition assignment 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not create Kafka transaction; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.transaction.KafkaTransactionManager.doBegin(KafkaTransactionManager.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1657)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:283)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1175)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:676)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the server log; most likely you don't have enough replicas to support transactions (3 by default). You can set it to 1 if you are only testing.

See broker properties `transaction.state.log.replication.factor` and `min.insync.replicas`.

> The replication factor for the transaction topic (set higher to ensure availability). Internal topic creation will fail until the cluster size meets this replication factor requirement.

and

> When a producer sets acks to "all" (or "-1"), this configuration specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered successful. If this minimum cannot be met, then the producer will raise an exception (either NotEnoughReplicas or NotEnoughReplicasAfterAppend).
>   When used together, min.insync.replicas and acks allow you to enforce greater durability guarantees. A typical scenario would be to create a topic with a replication factor of 3, set min.insync.replicas to 2, and produce with acks of "all". This will ensure that the producer raises an exception if a majority of replicas do not receive a write.